# Command to run heroku run rake db:migrate on production db when you also have a staging db in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I have a ruby on rails app, leveraging Postgres running in heroku. I have a staging environment and a production environment in heroku. I want to run the heroku run rake db:migrate on the production environment however I can find the command to do so, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How are the remote origins on Heroku named in your `.git/config`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just set the remote to get it to pick the right environment:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate --remote production
```

Comment: Femi thank you so much for your assistance unfortunately I am getting Error: Could not find git remote production

Comment: and remotes: heroku staging test, any other ideas? Again thanks for you help :)

Comment: Try `heroku run rake db:migrate --remote heroku` ? Basically if you list all the environments (I think you said you have **heroku**, **staging** and **test**) you should be able to specify one as the target.

Comment: thanks again for your help!! I ran that command, and ran heroku open and my staging app opened... I then looked at my url and the pictures from my production app are gone... not sure if that worked got any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When I ran heroku run rake db:migrate --remote it gave me three choices (heroku, staging & test) I ran the command: heroku run rake db:migrate --remote heroku and it worked!! (didn't understand that heroku was calling my production environment "heroku" and not production) thanks again for all your help